# File transfered using gcloud compute scp not showing in destination folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I transferred a approximately 500 MB csv file from my local workstation to master node home path of a spark cluster. I used the following command:
`gcloud compute scp local_file_path\file_name.csv cluster-name-m:~`
The output is as follows:

> file_name.csv         | 564076 kB |  87.1 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%

However, when I ssh into the master node using putty, the file does not show up in the home directory.
`ls` list empty directory, i.e. file is not listed.
The csv file is not displayed even in WinSCP.

But when I transferred another file, this time a python file `python_file.py`  using WinSCP, `ls` lists the `.py` file.

What is going wrong? because clearly gcloud shows transfer completed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if you use `gcloud compute ssh`? I suspect your putty credentials are different and correspond to a different user on the VM. Using `gcloud` for the copy and ssh will use the `google_compute_engine` key for both and shouldn't have the discrepancy. Alternatively check `/home/root` vs `/home/${user}` where `${user}` corresponds to the GCP|VM user.

Comment: perform a `find / -name "file_name.csv"` to find where your files are copied

Comment: Using the `~` to specify the home directory is not a good idea. This is an environment-specific value. For remote commands, whose environment will be used? The local system? The remote system? What if the command does not check the environment? Always specify full pathnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @John Hanley points to the issue.

The gcloud client and Putty client are two different users and hence different /home/user directories for each....

Instead of using `cluster-name-m:~` it should be `cluster-name-m:/home/user`